# Do I need virtuals in base class only?

Tags: c++

I have classes which are deriving further from derived classes such as:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void doSomething() {}
    virtual ~A{}
};

class B : public A
{
    //...something...
    void doSomething() {}
}

class C : public B
{
    //...something...
    void doSomething() {}
}

class D : public B, public C
{
    //...something...
    void doSomething() {}
}
```

My question is as said in title: Do I only need virtual functions in base class no matter how I am using them?

For example:

```
A *p = new B
delete p;

B *p2 = new C
delete p2;
```

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "needing virtual functions" because it makes little sense.

Comment: I provided an example of how I will use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overridden member functions are virtual if they are declared virtual in the parent class.
Which means that in your case

```
class C : public B
{
  //...something...
  void doSomething() {}
};
```

is equivalent to

```
class C : public B
{
  //...something...
  virtual void doSomething() {}
};
```

But the second option is more explicit and has less hidden meaning.

---

Since *c++11* a better option is:

```
class C : public B
{
  //...something...
  void doSomething() override {}
};
```

Additionally to showing your intent clearly, compilers will not compile code where the function signatures of the base class and the derived class do not match.

---

**Be sure to use virtual destructors in all inherited classes though.**

Comment: I would encourage usage of `void doSomething() override {}` instead.

Comment: @Alex Done, i was not sure if i should include it or not since the question is not tagged c++11, but well, we are nearly in 2015..

Comment: My personal opinion on this is that posting c++11 stuff on c++ should be encouraged as long as there is a c++03 version for those who still can't use c++11.

Comment: I'm not aware of what `override` does, but in C++03 do I only need user-defined virtual function in base class and virtual destructors in all inherited classes?

Comment: @user963241 Yes, but you will be thankful to yourself in the future if you repeat the keyword everywhere. And put virtual destructors on every class you intend to inherit from.

Comment: @user963241 see also: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override the essence. if you use c++11 use override instead because it makes sure your base class declared the function as virtual and the signatures match.